# MVC ASP - Stopping edit function from modifying fields to NULL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm trying to update ONLY specific data in my MVC application. Whenever I only edit a list view, I would edit the data (which works) but the rest of the database table would be NULL.

So for example -

**Fields in List View**

EmployeeID, FirsName, LastName, Email, Moderator, Admin

**Fields not in list view**

LoginID

---

So in my edit page, I have set up **read-only** for the info like **EmployeeID**, **FirstName**, **LastName**, and **Email** with two checkboxes for **Moderator** and **Admin** which are the only values I want to edit.

They work fine but when doing so, the data in the database for **LoginID** only becomes *NULL*.

Here is the code from my edit **GET** and **POST** methods

*GET*

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    EmpContext ec = new AppContext();
    Employee e = ec.Employees.Single(x => x.Id == id);
    return View();
}
```

*POST*

```cs
public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        EmpContext ec = new EmpContext();
        ec.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ec.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
            
    return View(employee);
}
```

So, how would I stop this executing in the field **LoginID** within the database when there are no text boxes at all for **LoginID**, even on the edit page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Attaching an existing but modified entity to the context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state?redirectedfrom=MSDN#attaching-an-existing-but-modified-entity-to-the-context)

> When you change the state to Modified **all the properties of the entity
> will be marked as modified** and **all the property values will be sent to
> the database when SaveChanges is called**.

Thus, this `Entry` method will update all the properties. For my recommendation, to update some Entity's columns only, you have to manually query the record and update desired properties only.

In your `Edit` (POST) method, change the `Entry()` way to:

```
EmpContext ec = new EmpContext();
Employee _employee = ec.Employees.Single(x => x.Id == employee.Id);

// TO-DO Update required properties only
_employee.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
ec.SaveChanges();
```